# What is the accepted way to create a JSON endpoint in my MVC4 app?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I would like to create an endpoint for an API.

Currently, I have a class inside my app that executes a stored procedure and returns a list of objects which I can easily turn into json like this:

```
public ActionResult Events()
{
    List<HobbsEventsMobile.Models.Event> events = HobbsEventsMobile.Models.Event.GetEventSummary();

    var jsonSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

    ViewBag.Events = jsonSerializer.Serialize(events);

    return View();
}
```

Then in my view:

```
@ViewBag.Events
```

But the problem is that this (obviously) renders the rest of the layout.

What can I do to set this up correctly so that this is an endpoint that only renders the JSON - and not the rest of the HTML? (Bonus if there is a way to do this for the entire controller)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC controllers already has a method for returning JSON:

```
public ActionResult Events()
{
    var events = HobbsEventsMobile.Models.Event.GetEventSummary();
    return Json(events, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

If you have controllers acting as JSON endpoints, you can create a Web API controller and just return the model:

```
public class EventController : ApiController
{
    public object Events()
    {
        return HobbsEventsMobile.Models.Event.GetEventSummary();
    }
}
```

You can read more about Web API here : http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api

Answer (score 2):

Just to extend the answer above, the `Json` function allows you to return multiple values, and you also can specify if you allow GET.  Whatever the name of the variable is will be the name in the Json payload.  For example:

```
JsonResult retVal = Json(new { page, total, rows }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

This will allow GETs, and will have values for `data.page`, `data.total` and `data.rows` (assuming you're using a parameter name of `data` in your `success()` function in your jQuery AJAX call).